# Angular ui-router and ng-grid - very laggy when switching between the pages/views :(

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router, ng-grid

I'm trying to build a single page application using ng-grid and ui-router. All works fine, but when the user navigates between the tabs/pages there are some funny behaviours in the ng-grid tables. It's a bit laggy and the tables look horrible when data coming in and swtiching between the pages

Is there a way that I could use a spinner/loading text/animation or anything else to fix this problem and have the transition between the pages smoother?

I have tried the ng-animation but that looks even worse.

Here's the full page [PLUNKR](http://embed.plnkr.co/5NWirySRNXzGOaZedv3a/preview)

Many thanks for your help, I can't get my head around :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing 'ngAnimate' from app.js:

```
.module ('myApp', ['ngAnimate','ngResource','ui.router','ngGrid'])
to:
.module ('myApp', ['ngResource','ui.router','ngGrid'])
```

fix your bad tables look when switching between the pages.

Also if you dont want to remove ngAnimate you could in bootstrap.css remove this:

```
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .15s linear;
  transition: opacity .15s linear;
}

.fade.in {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

this is the part that ruins the grid together with ngAnimate.